Liquibase command-line issues with Spring Boot fat jar
I’m trying to use the liquibase command-line to generate SQL to send to our DBAs.
It works fine for regular JAR files - I drop them into the liquibase_libs folder, run the CLI, and everything works.
However, this process doesn’t work for Spring Boot fat JARs because they have a different folder structure so Liquibase is unable to locate the changelog.
If I extract the changelog and specify it directly, then Liquibase can’t find the migration scripts because they’re not in the root of the JAR - they’re under the BOOT-INF/classes folder.
I tried add --search-path BOOT-INF/classes to the Liquibase command-line but it seems that is only for disk locations, not directories inside the JAR file.
Is there a workaround for this?
I have created this small GitHub project to demonstrate the issue.

I have worked around this issue with a few lines of scripting by unpacking the fat jar and repackaging it as a regular jar. Not ideal, but good enough.
